# Prevent double tapping android Prism xamarin

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I know this is a common questions,but I could not find an answer anywhere.

I want to prevent "quick double tapping" in Android.

I m using prism and Im not sure how I should implement/make use of  "CanNavigateAsync(INavigationParameters).

Suppose I have a toolbarItem to "Add something" and this is mapped to a command and I do the following:

```
    private DelegateCommand<MyVM> tappedToolbarItemCommand;
    public DelegateCommand<MyVM> TappedToolbarItemCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return tappedToolbarItemCommand
                   ?? (tappedToolbarItemCommand = new DelegateCommand<MyVM>(async args => await OnToolbarItemTapped(args))
                       .ObservesProperty(() => !IsBusy)
                       .ObservesCanExecute(CanExecute());
        }
    }

    private bool CanExecute()
    {
        if (IsBusy) return false;

        //HOW DO I MAKE USE OF "CanNavigateAsync"
        CanNavigateAsync(??) what parameters?
        return true;
    }

    private async Task OnToolbarItemTapped(MyVM vm)
    {           
        await NavigationService.NavigateAsync($"NavPage/{nameof(MyPage)}");                        
    }
```

So How do you prevent double tapping using Prism ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll be able to simply do this to prevent a double click:

```
  private bool _canNavigate = true;
  public bool CanNavigate
  {
        get { return _canNavigate; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _canNavigate, value); }
  }

 NavigateCommand = new DelegateCommand(Navigate).ObservesCanExecute((vm) => CanNavigate);

 async void Navigate()
 {
        CanNavigate = false;
        await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("ViewB");
        CanNavigate = true;
 }
```

There is related link.
https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/442

Comment: Lu thanks for your time.Unfortunately that does not work . When I click rapidly on a toolbarItem it brings the screen twice. I did try it before. I think there must be a different implementation.

Comment: that worked and I had to put "CanNavigate=true" in the constructor otherwise it would have been false to start with. But kind of not sure whether is the correct and current way of doing it.In Prism they have "IconfirmationAsync" etc.. when is that used?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old but I had a slightly different implementation because I had to change about 300+ `ICommands` since all of them were double tappable on Android.

So, I added the

```
private bool _canNavigate = true;
public bool CanNavigate
{
  get { return _canNavigate; }
  set { SetProperty(ref _canNavigate, value); }
}
```

to my base viewmodel.

Then I added this class to my project (`PrismBindableBase` is my base view model)

```
public class CanNavigateManager : IDisposable
{
    private readonly ICommand _command;
    private readonly PrismBindableBase _baseViewModel;

    public CanNavigateManager(ICommand command, PrismBindableBase baseViewModel)
    {
        _command = command ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(command));
        _baseViewModel = baseViewModel ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(baseViewModel));

        _baseViewModel.CanNavigate = false;
        ((Command)command).ChangeCanExecute();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _baseViewModel.CanNavigate = true;
        ((Command)_command).ChangeCanExecute();
    }
}
```

Then when I need to use it, I only need a single line of code as of C# 7 or 8. (or you could do the old school `using` with the `{}` surrounding)

```
protected virtual async Task ExecutePopupBackButton()
{
    using var mgr = new CanNavigateManager(PopupBackButtonCommand, this);
    await NavigationService.GoBackAsync();
}
```

Made my busy work going through all of my commands a little less busy.

Actually now that I look at this again, it could also be made into an extension method of `PrismBindableBase` so you could have something like

```
using _ = this.HandleCanNavigate(PopupBackButtonCommand);
```

Discard might not work here, not sure. Anyway...

"constant improvement is better than delayed perfection"?